# Creating relations in sentence using chunk tags (not NER) with NLTK | NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition, chunking

I am trying to create custom chunk tags and to extract relations from them. Following is the code that takes me to the cascaded chunk tree.

```
grammar = r"""
  NPH: {<DT|JJ|NN.*>+}          # Chunk sequences of DT, JJ, NN
  PPH: {<IN><NP>}               # Chunk prepositions followed by NP
  VPH: {<VB.*><NP|PP|CLAUSE>+$} # Chunk verbs and their arguments
  CLAUSE: {<NP><VP>}           # Chunk NP, VP
  """
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
sentence = [("Mary", "NN"), ("saw", "VBD"), ("the", "DT"), ("cat", "NN"),
    ("sit", "VB"), ("on", "IN"), ("the", "DT"), ("mat", "NN")]


chunked = cp.parse(sentence)
```

**Output -**

(S
  (NPH Mary/NN)
  saw/VBD
  (NPH the/DT cat/NN)
  sit/VB
  on/IN
  (NPH the/DT mat/NN))

Now I am trying to extract relations between the NPH tag values with the text in between using the nltk.sem.extract_rels function, BUT it seems to work ONLY on named entities generated with the ne_chunk function.

```
IN = re.compile(r'.*\bon\b')
for rel in nltk.sem.extract_rels('NPH', 'NPH', chunked,corpus='ieer',pattern = IN):
        print(nltk.sem.rtuple(rel))
```

This gives the following error -

**ValueError: your value for the subject type has not been recognized: NPH**

Is there an easy way to use only chunk tags to create relations as I don't really want to retrain the NER model to detect my chunk tags as respective named entities

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `extract_rels` ([doc](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sem/relextract.html#extract_rels))
   checks that arguments `subjclass` and `objclass` are known NE tags, hence the error with `NPH`.
2. The easy, ad hoc, way is to rewrite a customized `extract_rels` function (example below).

   ```
   import nltk
   import re

   grammar = r"""
     NPH: {<DT|JJ|NN.*>+}          # Chunk sequences of DT, JJ, NN
     PPH: {<IN><NP>}               # Chunk prepositions followed by NP
     VPH: {<VB.*><NP|PP|CLAUSE>+$} # Chunk verbs and their arguments
     CLAUSE: {<NP><VP>}           # Chunk NP, VP
     """
   cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
   sentence = [("Mary", "NN"), ("saw", "VBD"), ("the", "DT"), ("cat", "NN"),
       ("sit", "VB"), ("on", "IN"), ("the", "DT"), ("mat", "NN")]

   chunked = cp.parse(sentence)

   IN = re.compile(r'.*\bon\b')

   def extract_rels(subjclass, objclass, chunked, pattern):

       # padding because this function checks right context
       pairs = nltk.sem.relextract.tree2semi_rel(chunked) + [[[]]] 

       reldicts = nltk.sem.relextract.semi_rel2reldict(pairs)

       relfilter = lambda x: (x['subjclass'] == subjclass and
                              pattern.match(x['filler']) and
                              x['objclass'] == objclass)


       return list(filter(relfilter, reldicts))

   for e in extract_rels('NPH', 'NPH', chunked, pattern=IN):
       print(nltk.sem.rtuple(e))
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   [NPH: 'the/DT cat/NN'] 'sit/VB on/IN' [NPH: 'the/DT mat/NN']
   ```

Comment: Hi! Wonder why i didn't think of this. So, essentially you just removed the two lines of code on the top that checked if the subject and object class were part of the NE tag list right?

Comment: Essentially: yes. I also did some small modifications to make it work on your example, namely removing the `corpus="ieer` treatment, padding the output of `tree2semi_rel`, and removing the condition on the window size in the filter (not used in the example).

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to do this for POS tags as well? Additionally, don't think the padding in pairs is very important here - am i missing something on its use case

Comment: Not sure I get your first question: some fields (`"filler"`, `"subjtext"`, `"objtext"`, ...) in the items of `reldicts` contain strings in the format `"token/POS token/POS"`, so you can add conditions to match them in the filter.

Padding: if I understood correctly [semi_rel2reldict](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sem/relextract.html#semi_rel2reldict) stops if there is no right context, instead of considering an empty right context, padding just simulates an empty right context (which was necessary to match (cat, sit on, mat) in your example).